# ggplot text not rendering on pdf output with desired font

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, r-markdown

I would like for the font in my plot to be Calibri. Tried using the package extrafont, but when I knit on markdown i get a lot of warnings like "Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :font width unknown for character 0x74". And even though the plot is generated, it doesn't have any text (title, axys labels).

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2023-03-09'
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
extrafont::font_import()
```

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Example plot") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Calibri", size = 11))
```